# JIRA API to Create Issue Type as a Test

Tags: api, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

I am trying to create issue as a "Test" Type but getting below mentioned error
"Due date is required for Deployment tickets"

Call: Base_url/rest/api/2/issue

BODY:

```
{
    "fields": {
        "project": {
            "key":"JW"
        },
        "summary": "Test Summ",
        "description": "Test Desc",
        "issuetype": {
            "name": "Test"
        }
    }
}
```

ERROR Message:

```
{
    "errorMessages": [
        "Due date is required for Deployment tickets."
    ],
    "errors": {}
}
```

I already tried by adding the duedate field in body but it's not working.

Comment: Don't see a duedate added in the body!

Comment: Maybe this is a default required field?

Comment: You say that you already tried to add the duedate field in the body, but that it is not working. What is the error it is giving you when you add the duedate? The same error about the duedate being required?